# HTTP Status 404 - /EventTracker/greeting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to access the http://localhost:8080/EventTracker/greeting on my machine. However, I am getting a 404 error. I am following the PluralSight Introduction to Spring MVC4 tutorial and it seems like my code is matching the ones in the video. I am using the two java files WebConfig and WebAppInitializer to configure my application. Am I missing anything? I think I have copied over line by line but still not working.

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World");

        return "hello.jsp";
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context) );
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context) );
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");

    }

    private WebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight.WebConfig");
        return context;
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pluralsight")
public class WebConfig {

}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED 9/15 4:25 PM PST**
When using http://localhost:8080/EventTracker/greeting.html, I still get the same error, the error being:

```
16:24:41.925 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/EventTracker/greeting.html]
16:24:41.931 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EventTracker/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
16:24:41.931 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Can you post your DispatcherServlet.xml code?  It looks like your error has to do with your app not finding the correct mapping in your DispatcherServlet file.

Comment: I do not have any xml files for configuration. All configurations are done by the java files

Comment: If you decide to use xml files, I've posted an answer that should help you resolve your 404 error.  I'm not sure about only using java files.

Comment: Change this line `dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");` to dispatcher.addMapping("/*");

Comment: The change above didn't fix anything. Using the change, I wasn't even allowed to access my index page

Answer (score 6):

Because it was first question which I found in google and here no right answer, here is what helped me.

You should add in **WebAppInitializer.java** next

```
context.register(com.pluralsight.WebConfig.class);
```

So your file should looks like:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context) );
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context) );
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");

    }

    private WebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight.WebConfig");
        context.register(com.pluralsight.WebConfig.class);
        return context;
    }
}
```

Comment: this must to be marked as the right answer! this work for me

Answer (score 0):

I've never created a Spring MVC app that didn't have XML config files.  I'm sure it's possible, but I'd have to look into it.  If you don't mind using XML files for configuration, you could do something similar to the following (this is a little side project I did awhile ago to better familiarize myself with Spring MVC):

**web.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--if not using jsp, can omit this -->
<jsp-config> <!-- if taglib not inside jsp-config, will cause deployment errors -->
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/taglib/c.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

web.xml is the top tier of configuration.  From the above, the important thing to remember is that the  names which file (it will also be an XML file) is the dispatcher servlet file.  Whatever you include inside  tags will have -servlet.xml appended to it, so in this case, my dispatcher servlet will be a file called spring-servlet.xml.  The  tag tells the app which type of url patterns are associated with the dispatcher servlet.  So in this example, any url ending in .html will be handled by spring-servlet.xml.

If you are using JSP, make sure that all your  tags are within a  tag, otherwise it won't work correctly.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan
    base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />
    <!-- declares package where controller(s) stored. Don't need to declare indvd controllers -->

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> <!-- hello.jsp must be located in this directory for link to work -->
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

This is what the dispatcher servlet file looks like.  You can ignore the code at the top.  Based on the error you posted, my guess is that your java code has left out or incorrectly mapped your view resolver.  The view resolver is what converts the strings you pass into your controller (ie: hello) into your relative URL paths (ie: /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp).  For this to work correctly, make sure all your jsp files are in the same directory, and list that directory as part of your prefix value.  In this example, I stored all my jsp files inside a directory called jsp in my WEB-INF directory.  The suffix in this example is just the file extension.  Any file that isn't stored in this directory will cause your app to throw a 404 error when it tries to load that missing file.

I know this isn't exactly what you set out to do, but if you choose to use XML files, I hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The problem was that "native library" wasn't there in my Tomcat installation folder.
I solve that with:

> sudo apt-get install libtcnative-1

Then I had the problem my native library version was too old and I solve that with upgrade:

> sudo apt-get upgrade libtcnative-1

I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
context.register(WebConfig.class)
```

adding this in webapp intializer will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Your url `http://localhost:8080/EventTracker/greeting` doesn't match your dispatcher mapping: `dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");`. Try `http://localhost:8080/EventTracker/greeting.html`